# Order parent child records by parent group and children

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, multiple-columns

I need sort query results by specific two related columns. My table is:

```
Row no | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4
    1  |   1   |  X    |  1    |  5
    2  |   2   |  Y    |  1    |  6
    3  |   5   |  Z    |  2    |  7
    4  |   6   |  T    |  2    |  0
    5  |   7   |  T    |  3    |  0
    6  |   6   |  W    |  2    |  0
```

The values in `Col 4` represents the child record linked to `Col 1`.

So for `Row no = 1` the next child record is row 3, where `Col 1` holds the value of `Col 4` from the first row.

The next child row for row 3 is row 5, based on the link between `Col 1` and `Col 4`.

And I'd like to return this results:

```
Row no | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4
    1  |   1   |  X    |  1    |  5
    3  |   5   |  Z    |  2    |  7
    5  |   7   |  T    |  3    |  0    
    2  |   2   |  Y    |  1    |  6
    4  |   6   |  T    |  2    |  0
    6  |   6   |  W    |  2    |  0
```

So I want the ordering to show a Parent row, followed by it's child rows, before moving on to the next top level Parent row.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me, can you show what you've tried? Why do you have such strange rules and orders? Why do you have a consecutive order across rows?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. can you explain what toy mean by "Value in "Col 4" shows associated column which will be next in order"?

Comment: He wants the `Row no` to be sorted first by odd/even, then by the `Row no` itself in ascending order.

Comment: So you want a recursive order? The first record is the entry point, then you want all children via `Col4-->Col1`, if there is no child you want the next record without parent and all of it's  children via `Col4-->Col1`?

Comment: Value (number) in Col 4 shows all associated columns with this record. Associated columns have this same number in Col 1 and should be in the order immediately after the parent record. See my expected result above in post.

Comment: Record with value in Col 4 >0 is parent and have children records. The children records should be in order immediately after the parent record.

Comment: You still haven't explained your algorithm.  But my query gets the result you want.

Comment: i think you confuse columns with rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're after with a [Recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to find all the parent records and link them to their child records.

**Dummy table setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    (
      [Row no] INT ,
      [Col 1] INT ,
      [Col 2] VARCHAR(1) ,
      [Col 3] INT ,
      [Col 4] INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #Table1
        ( [Row no], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3], [Col 4] )
VALUES  ( 1, 1, 'X', 1, 5 ),
        ( 2, 2, 'Y', 1, 6 ),
        ( 3, 5, 'Z', 2, 7 ),
        ( 4, 6, 'T', 2, 0 ),
        ( 5, 7, 'T', 3, 0 ),
        ( 6, 6, 'W', 2, 0 );
```

**Recursive CTE:**

```
;WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.[Col 1] ) GroupNo
               FROM     #Table1 t1
               WHERE    t1.[Col 1] NOT IN ( SELECT  [Col 4] FROM #Table1 )
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   t.* ,
                        cte.GroupNo
               FROM     #Table1 t
                        INNER JOIN cte ON cte.[Col 4] = t.[Col 1]
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY cte.GroupNo , cte.[Row no]

DROP TABLE #Table1
```

This combines 2 queries with a `UNION ALL`. The first query finds the top level items where the value of `[Col 1]` does not appear in `[Col 4]`:

```
WHERE    t1.[Col 1] NOT IN ( SELECT  [Col 4] FROM #Table1 )
```

The second query finds the child records on the first query with this `JOIN`:

```
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.[Col 4] = t.[Col 1]
```

For the ordering, I've used the following to give the the results of the first query a `GroupNo`, which is used later to order the records:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.[Col 1] ) GroupNo
```

Comment: Thanks Tanner! This is what I need :) But is it also a good solution if the records of children have their own multiple records of children?

Comment: I've not tried that, as you never specified that in the question. Should be easy to test by modifying the data though.

Comment: If test  data is like below not sort correctly                                                                                                             INSERT  INTO #Table1
            ( [Row no], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3], [Col 4] )                         VALUES ( 1, 1, 'X', 1, 5 ),
        ( 2, 2, 'Y', 1, 0 ),
        ( 3, 5, 'Z', 2, 7 ),
        ( 4, 6, 'T', 2, 0 ),
        ( 5, 7, 'T', 3, 6 ),
        ( 6, 6, 'W', 2, 0 ),
        ( 7, 5, 'A', 2, 8 ),
        ( 8, 8, 'B', 2, 0 ),
        ( 9, 8, 'B', 2, 0 );

Comment: @Slavo please update your question with that information and also what you expect the desired output to be. or maybe even ask a new question as it is a pretty drastic change from your original requirement and renders my answer to your original question ineffective.