# need help in forming sql query

Tags: sql-server

```
ItemId      Name            parentId
1           A                null
2           b                null
3           c                 1
4           d                 2
5           e                 3         
6           f                 4
7           g                 2
```

hi i need help in create sql query.  I have a table  that contain 3 column itemid ,name ,parentitemid. i need a sql query that result  parent child relation.if parentitemid id null then it means root .please help

i need data like.

```
<1><3><5></5> </3></1>
```

Comment: 1 A Null,2 B null , 3 C 1, 4 D 2, 5 E 3,6 F 4, 7 G 2 data in rows

Comment: What have you already tried? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: i dont know how create recursive query for parent child relation,if u know answer of this please reply

Comment: good way to ask question,even though it is basic,you will get fast answers and even upvotes:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order parent child records by parent group and children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274590/order-parent-child-records-by-parent-group-and-children)

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use:

```
WITH HierarchicalTable
AS
(
    SELECT Id, ParentId, Name, 0 as [Level]
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YourTable.Id, YourTable.ParentId, YourTable.Name, [Level] + 1
        FROM YourTable
        JOIN HierarchicalTable ON HierarchicalTable.Id = YourTable.ParentId
)
SELECT [Level], Name FROM HierarchicalTable
```

Comment: i need xml like <a><c><e><e></c></a>

Answer (score 0):

This is excessively complicated solution, but it will work for your problem:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (ItemId int, Name char(1), parentId int,l int)
DECLARE @xml TABLE (s nvarchar(max), e nvarchar(max), parentId int, itemid int)
DECLARE @l int
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'a', NULL),(2, 'b', NULL),(3, 'c', 1),(4, 'd', 2),(5, 'e', 3),(6, 'f', 4),(7, 'g', 2)
) as t(ItemId, Name, parentId)
--Here we create recursive cte to obtain levels of nesting
), res AS (
    SELECT  *,
            1 [Level]
    FROM cte c
    where parentId IS null
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.*, 
            [Level]+1
    FROM res r
    INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.parentId = r.ItemId
)
--put results into temp table
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT *
FROM res 
--obtain max level
SELECT @l = MAX(l)
FROM @temp
--from  max level to 1 begin
WHILE @l > 0
BEGIN
    --if there is nodes with same parentid - concatinating them
    UPDATE x
    SET x.e = x.e + v.s + v.e
    FROM @xml x
    INNER JOIN @xml v
        ON v.parentId = x.parentId and v.e !=x.e;

    --here we merge table with results 
    -- first run <e></e>
    -- next run <c><e></e></c>
    -- next run <a><c><e></e></c></a>
    MERGE @xml AS target
    USING (
        SELECT '<'+ Name +'>' as s,'</'+ Name + '>' as e, parentId, ItemId
        FROM @temp 
        WHERE l = @l
        ) as source
    ON target.parentid = source.itemid
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES (source.s, source.e, source.parentId, source.ItemId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE 
            SET target.s = source.s + target.s, 
                target.e = target.e + source.e,
                target.parentid = source.parentid,
                target.itemid = source.itemid;
    --next level down
    SET @l = @l - 1

END

SELECT x --CAST(x as xml)
FROM (
    SELECT  s+e as x, 
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY itemid ORDER BY s ASC) as rn 
            --need that column to obtain first one of every string for itemid
    FROM @xml
    ) as c
WHERE c.rn = 1
--FOR XML PATH ('')
```

Output will be:

```
x
<a><c><e></e></c></a>
<b><d><f></f></d><g></g></b>
```

If you remove `--` near `FOR XML PATH ('')` and change this `SELECT x --CAST(x as xml)` to this `SELECT CAST(x as xml)` in last query you will get this:

```
<a>
  <c>
    <e />
  </c>
</a>
<b>
  <d>
    <f />
  </d>
  <g />
</b>
```

Comment: thanks gofr very helpful, but also need itemid and parentid with node

Comment: In your question - `<1><3><5></5> </3></1>` in comment to answer `<a><c><e><e></c></a>` now - something else. What exactly do you need?