# SQL Server 2014 - Update child value based on parent's total and child's data

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables

- **Parent** with columns `ID, total`
- **Child** with columns `ID, ParentID, BoundaryValue, ChildValue`

I have to update the child's records `ChildValue` column based on parent's total and child's `BoundaryValue` column.

Suppose Parent's total column for a `ParentID` is 20000 and Child's `ChildValue` column is 5000, I have to allocate 5000 if sum of all the Child's `ChildValue` column doesn't exceed 20000 (Parent's total).

Otherwise, I have to allocate the reminder of the Parent's total value.

If there is no more reminder amount in Parent's total, Child's `ChildValue` should be updated to zero. Records updated should be in the sequence of the ID.

I have tried with a recursive CTE but I couldn't get to the core with joining the two tables. I don't want to use cursor. Is there any option to do this with direct UPDATE or recursive CTE?

Comment: show your attempt at the solution and a sample set of data in a format that we can use rather than writing it all in text. you're much more likely to get a solution if there is a sample to start with.

Comment: Look at this sample for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274590/order-parent-child-records-by-parent-group-and-children/29277023#29277023. This is not an answer, just a demonstration of how you can present your problem.

Comment: Tanner, Thanks for your reply.  I am unable to get to the core of the query and that's why I didn't post.  In your example, how can I take the updated total from the parent?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL statements, some sample data as DML statements, and desired results.

Comment: @ManoharS i stated in my comment that the link was NOT an answer, just a sample of how you can present your question.

Comment: Please see the data below.  I want to update ChildValue column of Child table based on BoundaryValue column of Child table and Total column of Parent Table.

Create Table Parent
(
 ParentID BIGINT,
 Total NUMERIC(17,2)
)

Create Table Child
(
 ID BIGINT,
 ParentID BIGINT,
 BoundaryValue  NUMERIC(17,2),
 ChildValue NUMERIC(17,2),
 Created_Date DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Parent
VALUES(1, 30000),
 (2, 20000)

Comment: INSERT INTO Child
VALUES (1, 1, 4000, 0, '2016-12-01'),
 (2, 1, 5000, 0, '2016-12-02'),
 (3, 1, 8000, 0, '2016-12-03'),
 (4, 1, 12000, 0, '2016-12-04'),
 (5, 1, 10000, 0, '2016-12-05'),
 (6, 2, 4000, 0, '2016-12-11'),
 (7, 2, 5000, 0, '2016-12-12'),
 (8, 2, 8000, 0, '2016-12-13'),
 (9, 2, 12000, 0, '2016-12-14'),
 (10, 2, 10000, 0, '2016-12-15')

Comment: I want to update the Child table and need the query for that only.